# Get all paragraphs with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got the following code, that retrieves the first pargraph and echoes it:

```
function first_paragraph() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_para = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $post_content = $post->post_content;
  $post_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post_content);
  $output = preg_match_all('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $post_content, $matches);
  $first_para = $matches [1] [0];
  echo $first_para;
}
```

However, I would like to create a second function, that gets **all** paragraphs. Would anyone know how to amend the first code, so it retrieves  **all** paragraphs?

Comment: [dom+xpath](http://php.net/domxpath): `//p`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with PHP. Could you elaborate?

Comment: that's not really PHP. dom interfaces are pretty much the save everywhere, and xpath is how you query the dom. `//p` would find ALL `<p>` tags in an html/xhtml document.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class ?

```
<?php
$html='<p>First Paragraph</p>
<a href="somesite">click</a>
<p>Second ....</p>
<p>Third .. Phew last one!</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>"; // echoes all paragraph one by one
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
First Paragraph
Second ....
Third .. Phew last one!
```

Comment: I'm using WordPress, so I'm not familiar with that method. However, `$first_para = $matches[0][0];` spits out the first paragraph. `[0][1]` spits out the second. Can I loop through this array to show all?

Comment: @tmyie, Parsing HTML content with regex is really a bad idea and you will run into a lot issues. The above `DOM` is the right way to go. Try getting familiarized :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. You've used $html. Could that just as easily be $post_content? (See original post — I'm just trying to link it up with WordPress).

Comment: Yea you can directly pass your `$post_content` instead of `$html` of the `loadHTML()`.. So it will be like `loadHTML($post_content);`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give an example in your post? I'm still struggling to get them compatible .